# Line/Token based processing (java)

Tags: java, file, token, file-processing

I'm writing a program to read data from files with various sports statistics. Each line has information about a particular game, in say, basketball. If a particular line contains an "@" symbol, it means that one of the teams is playing at home. I'm trying to count the lines that contain an "@" and output that to the user as the Number of Games in which either team played at home. The first file has that 9 games were played at home for some team, but my output keeps printing out 0 rather than 9. How can I fix this?

Here's the relevant code:

```
public static void numGamesWithHomeTeam(String fileName) throws IOException{
    File statsFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(statsFile);
    String line = input1.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

    int count = 0;
    while(input1.hasNextLine()){
        if(line.contains("@")){
            count++;
            input1.nextLine();

        } else{
            input1.nextLine();
        }         
    } 
    System.out.println("Number of games with a home team: " + count);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line variable always has the first line's value. You should set line in the loop, something like that.

```
while(input1.hasNextLine()){
        if(line.contains("@")){
            count++;
            line = input1.nextLine();

    } else{
            line = input1.nextLine();
        }
```

Edit: On the second look your code has other problem: the last line is never checked. You should not initialize line (set to null) and do the check after nextLine():

```
public static void numGamesWithHomeTeam(String fileName) throws IOException{
File statsFile = new File(fileName);
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(statsFile);
String line = null;
Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

int count = 0;
while(input1.hasNextLine()){
    line = input1.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("@")){
        count++;
    }   
} 
System.out.println("Number of games with a home team: " + count);}
```